# A probability question w/ cumulative prob and uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I'm a beginner, I'm so sorry and I may apologize in advance if my question is too basic to be asked.

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqoW2.png):

> Let $X_1, \dotsc, X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables with cumulative distribution function $F$.
>   a) Write down a formula for the cumulative distribution function $F_{Y_n}$
>   of
>   $$Y_n = \max (X_1, \dotsc, X_n)$$ in terms of $F$. (Hint: $\{\omega:Y_n (\omega) \leqslant y\}=\bigcap_{i=1}^n \{\omega:X_i(\omega)\leqslant y\}$).
>
> b) Let $X_i$ be uniformly distributed on $\{1,...,5\}$. That is, $\mathbb P(X_i=k)=1/5$ for $k =1, \dotsc, 5$. Use part a. to compute 
>   $$q_n = \mathbb P(\max (X_1, \dotsc, X_n) = 5).$$ 
>   Does $q_n\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$? Should it?

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

---

Update: 
(a)
\begin{align}Pr(\max(X_1, \ldots, X_n) )&=  [{\int _{-\infty }^{y}f(y)\,dy}]^n   \end{align}

(b)
\begin{align}Pr(\max(X_1, \ldots, X_n) = 5)&=Pr(\max(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \leq 5)-Pr(\max(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \leq 4)\\&=1-Pr(\max(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \leq 4)= 1-
 {\int _{-\infty }^{y}f(y)\,dy} = 1- {\int _{-\infty }^{4}f(4)\,dy}\end{align}

Is my answer correct, thanks!

Comment: The issue is rarely about how basic  a quesiton is but what are your thoughts and attempts. Tell us where do you get stucked. Use more informative titles.  Try to type out the question so that it is searchable by other users.

Comment: Your diagram isn't a diagram; it is a scan of a textbook question. You needn't have inserted this as an image; you could have typed it out in the text of your question. By doing so, you would have made it more likely to get a response to your question.

Comment: Yea sure, I'll type out the question and title right away. Thanks so much for ur kind reminder.

Comment: I've updated the question, and correct the typo. Thank you for your suggestions as well.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I've updated it using MathJax.

Comment: any thoughts about the question?

Comment: Actually, I'm not quite familiar with prob and statistics. It's my second course about math in my college. It's really hard for me. But I'll try my best to understand it. So here I guess we should consider $Y_n$ as a variable of $F$, then we use CDF formula ${ F_{X}(x)=\int _{-\infty }^{x}f_{X}(t)\,dt.} $ to sum them up, but I just get stucked here.

Comment: Ok, I've included additional information in the post in that way u said.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for part (a):

$$Pr(\max(X_1, X_2) \leq y)=Pr(X_1 \leq y \text{ and } X_2 \leq y)=Pr(X_1 \leq y)Pr(X_2 \leq y)$$

Reasoning for first equality: if the maximum of two numbers are smaller or equal to $y$, each items must be smaller of equal to $y$. If each item is smaller than equal to $y$, the maximum must be smaller than equal to $y$ as well.

Reasoning for second equality: Independence.

Also note that $Pr(X_1 \leq y) =F(y)$.

Try to figure out write out what is $Pr(X_2 \leq y)$.

After you can do it for $2$ random variable, do it for $n$ random variables.

Hint for part $(b)$:

\begin{align}Pr(\max(X_1, \ldots, X_n) = 5)&=Pr(\max(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \leq 5)-Pr(\max(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \leq 4)\\&=1-Pr(\max(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \leq 4)\end{align}

Comment: So here, (part $a$) $F_{Y_n}$ = $Pr(X_1<=y)*Pr(X_2<=y)*..*Pr(X_n<=y) $   $=[\int _{-\infty }^{y}f(y)\,dy]$ $*n$, is that correct?

Comment: part a, note that $2 \times 2 \times 2 = 2^3 \neq 2 \times 3$. There is a mistake in part (a).

Comment: Horribly sorry for my bad LaTex thing. So based on that:


**(a)**
\begin{align}Pr(\max(X_1, \ldots, X_n) )&=  n * {\int _{-\infty }^{y}f(y)\,dy}   \end{align}

**(b)**
\begin{align}Pr(\max(X_1, \ldots, X_n) = 5)&=Pr(\max(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \leq 5)-Pr(\max(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \leq 4)\\&=1-Pr(\max(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \leq 4)= 1-
 {\int _{-\infty }^{y}f(y)\,dy} = 1- {\int _{-\infty }^{4}f(4)\,dy}\end{align}

Is my answer correct, thanks!

Comment: **Sorry for my incorrect LaTex typing. I've updated it**

Comment: Let's handle part a first before moving on to part b. a is not quite correct. $2\times 2 \times 2 = 2^3 \neq 3 \times 2$

Comment: Oh, so here. You said like 2x2x2=2^3 ≠ 3x2. So we should consider \begin{align}Pr(\max(X_1, \ldots, X_n) )&=   [{\int _{-\infty }^{y}f(y)\,dy}]^n   \end{align} other than $n * {\int _{-\infty }^{y}f(y)\,dy}$?  Did I understand correctly?

Comment: For each Pr of X<=y, they are the same ${\int _{-\infty }^{y}f(y)\,dy}$. Then we multiply them together, I think it should be ^n square.

Comment: $Pr(\max(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \leq y) = [F(y)]^n$ for part a.  For part b, you have to use part a.

Comment: So, for part B, since the distribution is symmetrical. Then we use part a's result 
\begin{align}Pr(\max(X_1, \ldots, X_n) = 5)&=Pr(\max(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \leq 5)-Pr(\max(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \leq 4)\\&=1-Pr(\max(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \leq 4)= 
 = 1- [{\int _{-\infty }^{4}f(4)\,dy}]^n \end{align},  is that correct? I'm sorry to understand it so slowly..

Comment: Actually $\int_{-\infty}^4 f(4) dy$ should be $\int_{-\infty}^4 f(y) dy$. Or you can just write it as $F(4)$. We should be able to evaluate $F(4)$ explicitly.  btw, it's ok to be slow, it is part of learning. I am a much slower learners than most people.

Comment: Just one more quick question, for the last part of (b):

When $q_n\to 1$, $F[y]^n$ need to be 0, 
so as $n\to\infty$, then $Pr(x_i)= 1/n = 0$, thus based on that, its CDF will also be 0?  So this conclusion should be $True$. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: what is $Pr(x_i)$?

Comment: Sorry. I mean $\mathbb P(X_i = k) = 1/n$

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(x_i)=\frac1n$ ? what is $n$ in this case?

Comment: My bad I didn't clarify it clearly. By the question "part (b) Let $X_i$ be uniformly distributed on $\{1,...,5\}$. That is, $\mathbb P(X_i=k)=1/5$ for $k =1, \dotsc, 5..$." Here, I wanna use $n$ to replace $5$, Let $X_i$ be uniformly distributed on $\{1,...,n\}$, for this $\mathbb P(X_i=n)=1/n$. Will it be the same case? I'm not pretty sure..

Comment: the previous question was purposely asked as $n$ has been use to indicate number of $X_i$. yup, $\mathbb{P}(X_i = k) = \frac15$.  Using that you should be able to find $F(4)$.